# CIFS File system is not working

Tags: mount, samba, fstab, cifs

I am trying to mount CIFS system. Using command line, I can mount filesystem, but using `fstab` file, its not getting mounted getting. See below error, so please suggest on this:

```
[4419376.493828] CIFS VFS: cifs_mount failed w/return code = -95
```

`mount -a` command is not working:

```
mount error(95): Operation not supported
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)
```

Comment: Did you read `man mount.cifs`? Please [edit] your Question and show us the command that works AND the `/etc/fstab` entry that doesn't work. Without these pieces of data, we can do nothing but guess. Do not reply via Add Comment.

Answer (score 1):

> return code = -95

There should be another part to this error. I tend to see this:

```
CIFS: VFS: Use of the less secure dialect vers=1.0 is not recommended unless required for access to very old servers
CIFS: VFS: cifs_mount failed w/return code = -95
```

and that is almost always the problem (beside a wrong user or password). You need to provide a version. Add 1 of these:

```
vers=2.0
vers=3.0
vers=3.1
vers=3.1.1
```

to the command after a `-o`.  `vers=1.0` is no longer valid. And try to avoid 2.0 too.